# What do we see if we observe the spaceship coming from a planet that's inside the event horizon?

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, event-horizon, interstellar-travel

Well, after watching the movie Interstellar, I just ask myself:

What would I see if I observe the ship that Cooper and the other girl in, coming from the planet inside the event horizon of Gargantua?

- I'm not sure if it's inside the event horizon or just on the orbit

Well, they say because of the black hole, time will be passed really slowly in the planet, about seven years an hour, so, if we in the other ship that the black guy in, outside the blackhole or on its orbit, what would we see? We just see the ship coming very slowly or?

Comment: The planet was not inside the event horizon of Gargantua.

Comment: Voted to close as incomprehensible to anyone who doesn't happen to watch the same shows the OP does.

Comment: @WillO If you haven't seen the Interstellar movie, you really should get a life and at least for a while step away from this popularity contest website ;)

Comment: At 7 years per hour things would appear about 60 thousand times slower, but also light would shift its frequency 60 thousand times down. The green light wavelength from 0.5 um would become 3 cm. This is a microwave range, so a radio telescope would be required instead of an optical telescope to see the travelers.

Comment: @WillO It's not your typical Hollywood sci-fi movie: Kip Thorne was heavily involved. See [here](http://interstellarfilm.wikia.com/wiki/Kip_Thorne).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No light escapes the event horizon of a black hole. So anything within the event horizon (specifically, Schwarzschild radius) of a black hole cannot be observed from outside of the event horizon.

Events that occur at or very near the event horizon of a black hole appear to occur very slowly to an observer far away.

For example, if Usain Bolt, current 100m dash world record holder ran 100m just outside of the event horizon of the black hole, we would watch him cross the finish line in 9s, assuming we were standing next to him. However, to an observer very far away, even as millenia pass, it would appear as if he has moved micrometers because he would appear to travel infinitely slower.

If he ran the dash just inside (or on) the event horizon, it would be as if the race never started.

Comment: 'it would appear as if he has moved micrometers *because the light would travel very slowly*' is a very suspicious statement

Comment: That's a very good point, I should edit my comment. Light always moves at the same speed. Time appears to move slower because the light is redshifted (so the wavelength of light grows, making the frequency smaller and hence time "spreads out" loosely speaking)